# I got syntax error on this python line but this line work fine in my pc

Tags: python

```
url = f'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id={pin}&date={date}'
```

i got syntax error on this python code but this line work fine in my pc

Comment: Add your Python version information.

Comment: On the installation that's giving the syntax error are you using Python version 3.6+ (required for f-sstrings)?